# how solve unknow entity button error?

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.mainBtn1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        MyActivity.setContentView(R.layout.sib-aval);
    }

    });
}
}
```

Comment: what error, show here?

Comment: Unknow entity 'button'

Comment: What you to do using `MyActivity.setContentView(R.layout.sib-aval);` line?

Comment: To showing sib-aval layout after clicking button

Comment: Could you provide the exact error? Does the code compile? Where the error is printed?

Answer (score 0):

MyActivity must be MainActivity, check removing this:

```
MyActivity.setContentView(R.layout.sib-aval);
```

For this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.sib-aval);
```

Comment: and check if the button is in the layout main

Comment: If there where no button in layout, it would result in NullPointerException, since findVIewById would return null

Comment: I delete myactivity and i created button in layout but exist that error

Comment: paste the xml please